# Games that use R2/L2 buttons on PSP

Tags: psp

**How do games utilize the R2 and L2 buttons on a PSP?**

One game in particular that comes to mind is Xenogears, it was originally on the PS One but can be played on PSP. While you're exploring the world you can quickly get in and out of your gear by pushing these 2 buttons simultaneously. But when I use the buttons on top of the PSP, they act as R1 and L1, thus it just spins my map around acting like it would normally on the PS One version.

I know there are other games that require you to use the R2 and L2 buttons, and these games are available on both the PS One and PSP systems. So how could you use these buttons to establish normal gameplay?

Comment: Typically they're mapped to the rear touchpad. I know that's the default on most PS One games. You can press and hold the home button to access the configuration menu for the game.

Comment: @FooBarrigno The PSP doesn't have a rear touchpad. I guess you mean the Vita?

Comment: ah, yes, sorry about the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When playing PS1 games on PSP, push the HOME button while the game is running. There should be a controls option where you can then customize the controls.
Individual customization are saved for every single game.

Sources:

[Playstation Forum](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PSP/How-do-you-do-L2-R2-buttons-when-playing-ps1-games-on-a-psp/td-p/2289560)

[PSU Forum](http://www.psu.com/forums/showthread.php/208417-Always-wondered-about-R2-and-L2-buttons-for-PSone-classics-on-a-PSP)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Home menu to set the controls. There are several options for choosing buttons to represent L2/R2. Fortunately, since no PS1 games on the store have different input meanings for the d-pad and the analog stick (that I know of), either the d-pad or the analog stick makes a good candidate for L2/R2.

By default, L2 is analog left and R2 is analog right, but you can switch the analog stick and d-pad for some games, or have L2 and R2 on the triggers and L1 and R1 on the analog stick. You can also set each of the controls to something else entirely and fully customize them.